# trying to open a page using a link codeigniter php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to open a page on clicking on a link in my codeigniter application. This is the snippet of my attempt

at the controller level this is snippet

```
//load return policy
   function returnpolicy()
   {

        $this->load->view("return_policy");
   }
```

at the view level this is the snippet

```
<div class="toggle">
                    <a href="<?php  echo site_url()."/"."gotopolicy/returnpolicy" ?>" class="toggle-title">Return Policy</a>

                </div>
```

on clicking on the link it does not navigate to the page. please what am I missing. am new to codeigniter

Comment: what is the error appears to you ?

Comment: try to remove `class="toggle-title"`

Comment: @AbanoubMakram cant find any error

Comment: Did you set your base url in config.php `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';` Because if url has ip in it links may not work

Comment: Make sure you have named controller like: `filename:  Gotopolicy.php` and `class Gotopolicy extends CI_Controller {}` where only the first letter upper case.

Comment: And try `<?php echo anchor('gotopolicy/returnpolicy', 'Return Policy');?>` make sure you have autoloaded url helper `$autoload['helper'] = array('url');`

Answer (score 1):

You should understand the difference between `site_url` and `base_url` first

```
echo base_url(); // http://example.com/website
echo site_url(); // http://example.com/website/index.php
```

You can rewrite it as follows :

```
<?php  echo site_url('controller/method');?>
```

In HMVC

```
<?php  echo site_url('module/controller/method');?>
```

So in your case

```
<a href="<?php  echo site_url('gotopolicy/returnpolicy');?>" class="toggle-title">Return Policy</a>
```

you can use the `URL` helper this way to generate an `<a>` tag

`anchor(uri segments, text, attributes)`

So... to use it...

```
<?php echo anchor('gotopolicy/returnpolicy', 'Return Policy', 'class="toggle-title"') ?>
```

Possible issue could be of htaccess,

create a file `.htaccess` in your root CI folder

and add below contents to it

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Make `$config['index_page'] = "";`

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `class="toggle-title"`
or try this

```
<div >
   <a href="<?=base_url()?>/Gotopolicy/returnpolicy">Return Policy</a>
</div>
```

Comment: it did not navigate to the page